# Footer does not move down

Tags: css, html, footer

When my app-container div expands, it will overflow my footer. My footer should move down away from the app-container (or the entire wrapper respectively), but it does not, and I don't manage to find what's wrong.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="wrapperbackground">
  <div class="app-container">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<footer>
 <div class="footerwrapper">
 </div>
</footer>
```

CSS code:

```
.wrapper { text-align:center;  min-height: 900px; }

.wrapperbackground { background-color: #C63D0F; height:375px; padding: 25px 0px; }

.app-container {
    border: 1px dotted;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height:300px;
    width:775px;
    background-color:#FDF3E7;
    overflow:hidden;
}

footer {
    height:100%;
    border-top: 1px dashed #FDF3E7;
    background-color:#250800;
    text-align:left;
}

.footerwrapper { border-bottom: 1px dotted #3B3738;padding:50px;min-height:200px; background-color:#220a03; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Would be nice if someone could help me. I agree that the CSS code is a little bit messy, and that's perhaps the problem.

Comment: seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/Rs5q8/

Comment: The problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rs5q8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to move `.wrapperbackground` to be before `.app-container` so it is no longer wrapping it. Then on '.wrapperbackground' apply:

`position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: 200px;`

Then on `.wrapper` apply `position: relative;` for good measure and more portability.

See this updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p57rK/1/

Comment: Alright, thank you. But isn't there a way to avoid removing the height from the <code>.wrapperbackground</code>? I'd like to have the body background visible.

Comment: Sure, you can add it back in and this will still work. I just thought it was unintentional. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, but didn't mean the height in the app-container, but the height in the wrapperbackground. :-)

Comment: Ahhh I get you. I have updated the fiddle and answer with what I think you are after. http://jsfiddle.net/p57rK/1/

Comment: Almost, I guess. The wrapper shouldn't be absolute I guess, because it's not attached to the top. Again, I made a better explanation.. I don't want the orange wrapperbackground to exceed the app-container. However, I want to let the footer not collide with it either. http://jsfiddle.net/p57rK/3/

Comment: Can you not apply padding / margin or adjust the top value to get this where it needs to be form my latest fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, could be. But as http://jsfiddle.net/p57rK/4/ shows, the footer is still not moving dynamically.. (I added height in the wrapper, otherwise everything would be overflowed)

Comment: Remove the height from the wrapper as that will cut everything off. And make sure wrapper background is not wrapping the app-container. http://jsfiddle.net/GR5tn/1/ look for the comments in the hmtl.